# Is there a more efficient way to copy multi-dimmension array (deep copy)?

Tags: java

I am going to copy an `int [][]` array as below:

```
int [][] intArray={{1,2},{1,2,3},{3,5}};
int [][] intArrayBak=new int[3][];
System.arraycopy(intArray,0,intArrayBak,0,intArray.length);
intArrayBak[2][1]=100;

for(int i=0;i<intArray.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<intArray[i].length;j++)
        System.out.println(intArray[i][j]+" ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

The result shows that intArray[2][1] is also changed to 100. I want to make a deep copy.

Is there any more efficient way other than for loop as below:

```
for (int i=0;i<intArray.length;i++) 
    System.arraycopy(intArray[i],0,intArrayBak[i],0,intArray[i].length);
```

Comment: @ZHI I think not. But you can use one-dimensional array to simulate multi-dimensional array in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would base it on [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)):

```
public static int[][] deepCopy(int[][] array) {
    int[][] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length); // shallow
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        result[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array[i], array[i].length);
    return result;
}
```

You are guaranteed that the implementation of the JDK library method will be as efficient as it can be.

Comment: Why create a copy of the outer array as opposed to just directly creating a new (empty) int[][] to then populate in the for loop?

Comment: @ZHI I think the code is correct. Looks like a deep copy to me. The first first copyOf only allocates the outer array. "new int[array.length][]", as Brett suggested, would also work.

Comment: *"You are guaranteed that the implementation of the JDK library method will be as efficient as it can be."* - There is no such guarantee.  0) Show me where Oracle guarantee that ...  1) The class libraries are optimized for the general case, not all specific cases.  You may be able to write code that is tuned for specific cases that is faster than.  2) There have (in the past) been examples where performance of certain standard library methods was poor.

Comment: @StephenC for other contexts sure, but code for copying arrays is surely among the most basic, well understood and easy to optimise of any code. Surely any JDK implementation would be "efficient"

Answer (score 0):

As Java does not store 2d-arrays continuously, it cannot be avoided to loop over the first dimension and copy each subarray separately.

Note that `System.arraycopy` expects an the destination to be allocated, so you have to allocate a new array first. Using `java.util.Arrays#copyOf` is a simpler interface than `System.arraycopy`:

```
for (int i=0;i<intArray.length;i++)
   intArrayBak[i]=Arrays.copyOf(intArray[i],intArray[i].length);
```

The more verbose alternative is this:

```
// fixed arraycopy example
for (int i=0;i<intArray.length;i++) {
   intArrayBak[i] = new int[intArray[i].length]; // zeroing
   System.arraycopy(intArray[i],0,intArrayBak[i],0,intArray[i].length);
}
```

I would prefer the copyOf version, as it is more readable. Internally, it is implemented via `System.arraycopy` so I would not expect it to be significantly faster (but it should certainly not be slower).